# Можно ли закрыть модальное окно в disnake?

Tags: python, discord, disnake

Пишу своего бота на disnake, и необходимо было добавить модальное окно. Взял всё из документации по [disnake](https://ru.guide.disnake.dev/interactions/modals). Там была такая проблема, как закрытие окна только если отправить в inter.response сообщение. Мне же такого не нужно.
Итог вопроса: Можно ли закрыть модальное окно disnake не отправляя сообщения

Вот код:

```
class MyModal(disnake.ui.Modal):
def __init__(self):
    # Детали модального окна и его компонентов
    components = [
        disnake.ui.TextInput(
            label="Name",
            placeholder="Foo Tag",
            custom_id="название",
            style=TextInputStyle.short,
            max_length=50,
        ),
        disnake.ui.TextInput(
            label="Description",
            placeholder="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
            custom_id="описание",
            style=TextInputStyle.paragraph,
        ),
    ]
    super().__init__(
        title="Create Tag",
        custom_id="create_tag",
        components=components,
    )

# Обработка ответа, после отправки модального окна
async def callback(self, inter: disnake.ModalInteraction):
    embed = disnake.Embed(title="Создание тега")
    for key, value in inter.text_values.items():
        embed.add_field(
            name=key.capitalize(),
            value=value[:1024],
            inline=False,
        )
    await inter.response.send_message(embed=embed)# эта часть и закрывает модальное окно, отправляя сообщение. Мне нужно что бы окно закрывалось без сообщения
```

Answer (score 0):

Убери в строке с отправкой сообщения embed=embed и оставь пустые скобки, как я показал ниже, тогда бот будет пытаться отправлять пустое сообщение (правда зачем тебе тогда вообще модалка если ты не увидишь заполненный результат (к слову её можно дублировать на другой канал, могу подсказать как)). При попытке отправки пустого сообщения бот выдаст ошибку, но будет спокойно работать дальше, этакий костыль.

```
# Обработка ответа, после отправки модального окна
async def callback(self, inter: disnake.ModalInteraction):
    embed = disnake.Embed(title="Создание тега")
    for key, value in inter.text_values.items():
        embed.add_field(
            name=key.capitalize(),
            value=value[:1024],
            inline=False,
        )
    await inter.response.send_message()# эта часть и закрывает модальное окно
```